# Certificate error: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I am making proxy server. I used [Implementing a Multithreaded HTTP/HTTPS Debugging Proxy Server in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93301/Implementing-a-Multithreaded-HTTP-HTTPS-Debugging) as a reference.

The piece of code:

```
    private void ProccessRequest(Socket client)
    {
        // Create network stream from socket for read and write data
        Stream networkStream = new NetworkStream(client, true);
        // Create stream reader for read data from socket
        StreamReader clientReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
        // For read and write data to socket
        // Same for http and https requests
        Stream clientStream = networkStream;            

        try
        {
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                // Get first request line
                string str = clientReader.ReadLine();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                {
                    string[] tmpStr = str.Split(SapceSplit, 3);

                    String method = tmpStr[0];
                    String remoteUrl = tmpStr[1];

                    if (method.Equals("CONNECT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        remoteUrl = "https://" + remoteUrl;

                        // Read all information from socket
                        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clientReader.ReadLine())) ;

                        // Tell browser that connection established
                        StreamWriter connectWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                        connectWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established");
                        connectWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("Timestamp: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                        connectWriter.WriteLine();
                        connectWriter.Flush();

                        // Create SSL stream
                        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(networkStream, false);
                        // Set sertificate for decrypt the client's traffic
                        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(_certificate, false, 
                            SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2, true);

                        // HTTPS server created - we can now decrypt the client's traffic
                        clientReader = new StreamReader(sslStream);
                        clientStream = sslStream;
                        // read the new http command.
                        str = clientReader.ReadLine();
                        tmpStr = str.Split(SapceSplit, 3);
                        method = tmpStr[0].ToUpper();
                        remoteUrl = remoteUrl + tmpStr[1];
                    }
```

But on this line:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(_certificate, false, 
        SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2, true);
```

I am getting the error: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

I am loading certificate with private key:

```
_certificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\\cert2.pfx", "1234", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to start SSL (including certificate exchange) *before* you put any HTTP on the connection.

Comment: Richard, thank you for the answer. What do you mean start SSL?

Comment: Converting the TCP socket into a SSL stream (wrapping in an `SslStream`).

Comment: I am doing it: SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(networkStream, false); Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You are, but *after* sending HTTP headers.

Comment: But as I understand, I need to send non-ssl established information first. Do you know how to correct the code? I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't. (Otherwise the Host header could be sent, thus avoiding the need of one IP address per SSL site until SSL was enhanced to include host information.) At this point you really need to read the HTTP and SSL RFCs in detail to answer this kind of question.

Comment: @user3763845, if you want to send anything in HTTP session non-ssl, then this would be in a separate stream.

Comment: I don't send Host header. I am sending header to the server that connection was established. And then I am reading headers from the server with secure connection. Thank you, I will check RFC. But if you can, please, show the mistake in the code.

Comment: @user3763845 - Please revisit your question. Take the information you put in a comment and add it to the question by clicking *Edit*. Then delete the comment.

Comment: @user3763845, if you provide a more complete listing, i can probably point at possible implementations. But what you need to do is say 'CONNECT' or whatever on the server, then make ANOTHER request from the client, this time via ssl.

Comment: @zaitsman, I have updated the code above. And I figured out that for some brothers it works fine. But I checked for browsers, that my proxy server doesn't work, other proxy server (without source) it works greate.

Comment: Do you get any ssl errors in the browsers that don't work? the error is actually suggesting thay might not trust your cert.

Comment: @zaitsman, I just found that Browser was ignoring certificate errors. Yes, browser is getting error AuthorityInvalid.

Comment: Checked with Fiddler, everything is OK. The problem with certificate? But how to solve it?

Comment: @user3763845 if the certificate is invalid, install it on your computer in the Trusted Root Certificate store. To do that: press Win+R then type mmc, then enter, then press Ctrl-m, then click 'Certificates' select 'Local Computer', navigate to 'Root Certificate Authorities' - 'Certificates'. Right click anywhere and import, then try again.

Comment: @zaitsman, thank you for helping! It works. But only if I am using CN=host_name. It means that I need to install certificate for each site is going via proxy server. I think there are must be other solution?

Comment: @user3763845 what you're doing is known as Man in the middle attack on the ssl. one way to approach this is to generate a ssl certificate for each host name requested. so long as the browser trusts your ca, it will trust all certs. This is how BurpSuite works.

Comment: I have tested Fiddler. In Trusted Root I can see only one certificate from Fiddler, so it means that they install only one certificate. Maybe I can install one main certificate and they generate for each host?